# How to use custom colorscheme with `\tdplotsphericalsurfaceplot` from `tikz-3dplot`

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, tikz-3dplot

As the title suggest I am trying to use a different color scheme than is currently the default in the `tikz-3dplot` package for the `\tdplotsphericalsurfaceplot` command if one uses the option `parametricfill`.

Here is a MWE with two colors that I would like to have instead of the once used right now. Why two colors? Because I use a colorfunction that simply devides my parameter space into two regions: `colorFunc(\t)=ifthenelse(\t<pi/2,0,1);`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}

\definecolor{color1}{RGB}{ 86, 180, 233} % Skyblue
\definecolor{color2}{RGB}{230, 159,   0} % Orange

\begin{document}


\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{135}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,line join=bevel,tdplot_main_coords, 
        fill opacity=1,
        declare function={ colorFunc(\t)=ifthenelse(\t<pi/2,0,1);}]
    \pgfsetlinewidth{.1pt}
    \tdplotsphericalsurfaceplot[parametricfill]{64}{32}%
            {1.3*(1/8*sqrt(5/pi)*(1+3*cos(2*\tdplottheta)))}%
            {black}%
            {colorFunc(\tdplottheta*2)}%
        {\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};}%
        {\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};}%
        {\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{$z$};}%
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Note: Maybe it is possible to somehow compute the color-coordinates of my two colors and set them in my `colorFunc`. However, it seems that the plotrange is rescaled, so no matter which values I enter into my `colorFunc` the resulting plot is always the same, i.e. `colorFunc(\t)=ifthenelse(\t<pi/2,0,pi*2/3);` yields the same plot.

Comment: In this case we have the result  of the `colorFunc` is 0 or 1, what's the role  of those  two  numbers,  try to change them with 90 and 180   `colorFunc(\t)=ifthenelse(\t<pi/2,90,180);`

Comment: In my last paragraph I wrote that changing the values of the colorFunc does not change anything. Unfortunately :/.

Comment: In my case with 90 and 180 the colors are reversed

Comment: Ah. I see. This would be due to the periodicity of the colorfunction. My bad.. But this still does not allow me to choose the colors I want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like you are already able to customize the color. I am not quiet sure what is your problem. So I would just explain everything.

## What is the 6th argument of `\tdplotsphericalsurfaceplot`?

(I am talking about the blank you filled by `colorFunc(\tdplottheta*2)`)

This blank allows you to fill in a math expression which is based on `\tdplotr`, `\tdplottheta`, and `\tdplotphi`, and returns a real number. Intuitively, if your expression returns `60`, than the color HSB(60,1,1) is used, which is the pure yellow. Similarly if your expression returns `300`, it is HSB(300,1,1) the purple.

Technically, your expression is put into

> ```
> \pgfmathsetmacro{\colorarg}{#5}
> ```

(it is `#5` but not `#6` because of, well, we would see it later)

Therefor you can write everything accepted by PGF-math engine. In the most extreme case, you can pass `random(0,360)`.

[image]

## Why do I get two colors even if my expression returns a constant?

Things get weird if the plot contains negative radius. In your case, `cos` is sometimes as negative as -1, producing the **doughnut** part of the plot. In the following figure, I wrote `3` as the expression. So *normally* it should be `HSB(3,0,0)`, a reddish color. But how is the **doughnut** now cyanish?

[image]

The answer is that `tikz-3dplot` assumes users use `\tdplotphi` as the expression. Since the point (-r,θ,φ) coincides with the point (r,θ+180,-φ), `tikz-3dplot` adds `180` to your expression whenever it comes to the case of negative radius.

To get over this, make sure your plot is always of positive radius, or make sure that your expression satisfies

> func(-r,θ,φ) = func(r,θ+180,-φ)+180   (mod 360)

For instance func(-r,θ,φ) = 5θ + φ^2/90

## I want full access of color

Redefine `\tdplotdosurfaceplot`. This command is used to draw single pieces of rectangles. (And its 5th argument is `\tdplotsphericalsurfaceplot`'s 6th argument.) Thus it is a bit long and contains ugly details. So please focus on the `\ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{parametricfill}}` part

[image]

```
\renewcommand\tdplotdosurfaceplot[6]{
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\nextphi}{\curphi + \tdplotsuperfudge*\viewphistep}
    \begin{scope}[opacity=1]
        \tdplotcheckdiff{\nextphi}{360}{\origviewphistep}{#2}{}
        \tdplotcheckdiff{\nextphi}{0}{\origviewphistep}{#2}{}
        \tdplotcheckdiff{\nextphi}{90}{\origviewphistep}{#3}{}
        \tdplotcheckdiff{\nextphi}{450}{\origviewphistep}{#3}{}
    \end{scope}
    \foreach \curtheta in{\viewthetastart,\viewthetainc,...,\viewthetaend}{
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\curlongitude}{90 - \curphi}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\curlatitude}{90 - \curtheta}
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\leftright}{-1.0}}{\pgfmathsetmacro{\curphi}{\curphi - \origviewphistep}}{}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\tdplottheta}{mod(\curtheta,360)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\tdplotphi}{mod(\curphi,360)}
        \pgfmathparse{\tdplotphi < 0}
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\pgfmathresult}{1}}{\pgfmathsetmacro{\tdplotphi}{\tdplotphi + 360}}{}
        \pgfmathparse{\tdplottheta > \tdplotuppertheta}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\logictest}{1 - \pgfmathresult}
        \pgfmathparse{\tdplottheta < \tdplotlowertheta}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\logictest}{\logictest * (1 - \pgfmathresult)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\tdplottheta}{\tdplottheta + \viewthetastep}
        \pgfmathparse{\tdplottheta > \tdplotuppertheta}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\logictest}{\logictest * (1 - \pgfmathresult)}
        \pgfmathparse{\tdplottheta < \tdplotlowertheta}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\logictest}{\logictest * (1 - \pgfmathresult)}
        \pgfmathparse{\tdplotphi > \tdplotupperphi}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\logictest}{\logictest * (1 - \pgfmathresult)}
        \pgfmathparse{\tdplotphi < \tdplotlowerphi}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\logictest}{\logictest * (1 - \pgfmathresult)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\tdplotphi}{\tdplotphi + \viewphistep}
        \pgfmathparse{\tdplotphi < 0}
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\pgfmathresult}{1}}{\pgfmathsetmacro{\tdplotphi}{\tdplotphi + 360}}{}%
        \pgfmathparse{\tdplotphi > \tdplotupperphi}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\logictest}{\logictest * (1 - \pgfmathresult)}
        \pgfmathparse{\tdplotphi < \tdplotlowerphi}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\logictest}{\logictest * (1 - \pgfmathresult)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\tdplottheta}{\curtheta}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\tdplotphi}{\curphi}

%%%%%%% not important ↑↑↑↑↑↑
%%%%%%% yes important ↓↓↓↓↓↓

        \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{parametricfill}}{
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\radius}{#1}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\x{\radius*sin(\tdplottheta)*cos(\tdplotphi)}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\y{\radius*sin(\tdplottheta)*sin(\tdplotphi)}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\z{\radius*cos(\tdplottheta)}

            \pgfmathsetmacro\r{(\x+.4)}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\g{(\y+.4)}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\b{(\z+.8)/2}

            \definecolor{tdplotfillcolor}{rgb}{\r,\g,\b}
            \color{tdplotfillcolor}
        }{}
        \pgfsetstrokeopacity{0}

%%%%%%% yes important ↑↑↑↑↑↑
%%%%%%% not important ↓↓↓↓↓↓

        \ifthenelse{\equal{\leftright}{-1.0}}{\pgfmathsetmacro{\curphi}{\curphi + \origviewphistep}}{}
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\logictest}{1.0}}{%
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\radius}{abs(#1)}
            \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointspherical{\curlongitude}{\curlatitude}{\radius}}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\tdplotphi}{\curphi + \viewphistep}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\radius}{abs(#1)}
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointspherical{\curlongitude - \viewphistep}{\curlatitude}{\radius}}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\tdplottheta}{\curtheta + \viewthetastep}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\radius}{abs(#1)}
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointspherical{\curlongitude - \viewphistep}{\curlatitude - \viewthetastep}{\radius}}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\tdplotphi}{\curphi}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\radius}{abs(#1)}
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointspherical{\curlongitude}{\curlatitude - \viewthetastep}{\radius}}
            \pgfpathclose
            \pgfusepath{fill,stroke}
        }{}
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer, I like that you also explain how the original function works, because this was (obviously ^^) also not clear to me.