# Gray shaded sphere with tikz-3dplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, tikz-3dplot

How do I draw a grayscale shaded sphere with `tikz-3dplot`? I tried using `\tdplotsphericalsurfaceplot` with radius equal to `1`, and `parametricfill` depending on the spherical angles. However, it looks like I can only prescribe the color's hue (in HSB space), according to the [following post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256343/), which does not suit me. I could go all the way and redefine  `\tdplotdosurfaceplot`, but that seems overkill.

Let me emphasize that I want *true* 3D drawing (the rest of my picture *requires* 3D coordinates: I need to draw arcs), so I cannot use 2D tricks such as

```
\draw [ball color=white] (0,0,0) circle (1) ;
```

so this is *not* a duplicate of [how-to-draw-a-shaded-sphere](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54193/). I explicitly want a 3d drawing, preferably with `tikz-3dplot`, though I'm open to other 3d packages.

Here are two MWEs: the first sphere uses uniform coloring, while the second uses a linear combination of the spherical angles:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
\tdplotsphericalsurfaceplot[parametricfill]{24}{24}{1} {black}{50}{}{}{}
\begin{scope}[xshift=4cm]
\tdplotsphericalsurfaceplot[parametricfill]{24}{24}{1} {black}{\tdplottheta+\tdplotphi}{}{}{}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I would also like to get rid of the parametric lines... Maybe this is not the right package to work with, or the right command in the package.
[image]

Comment: [tag:pgfplots] grant you full access by default. Keywords: `surf` and `point meta`

Comment: If you want 'true 3D', PGF/Ti*k*Z is not the package to choose. You can use it to fake 3D in 2D, but it does not do real 3D at all. `tikz-3dplot` helps do calculations required to fake 3D in 2D.

Comment: @cfr I'll be happy to know other options. My goal is to draw a circular arc on the sphere, given 3d coordinates of its endpoints.

Comment: Thanks to all answers, I can now rephrase my question: I want to draw circular arcs on a gray shaded sphere, with actual 3d coordinates of the spherical points. `tikz-3dplot` is reasonably good at drawing circular arcs, but poor at shading the sphere. `pgfplots` excels at drawing graphs, including the sphere, but afaik does not know how to draw circular arcs (or in a very complicated way). Moreover the two do not work well together. Any idea of a package that would allow me to reach both?

Answer (score 2):

Better use `pgfplots` (adapted from [this post](http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/10257/farbdarstellungsmoglichkeiten-mit-tikz-3dplot/17716)).  The parametric fill with `\theta+\phi` looks pretty weird in my opinion.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    [
      width=6cm,height=6cm,
      axis equal,enlargelimits=false,
      axis lines=none,
      domain=0:180,samples=21,
      y domain=0:360,samples y=21,
      colormap/blackwhite,
      view={100}{10},
    ]
    \addplot3
      [
        surf,
        z buffer=sort,
        shader=flat,
        point meta={acos(z/sqrt(x*x+y*y+z*z)) + atan2(y,x)}
      ] (
        {sin(x)*cos(y)},
        {sin(x)*sin(y)},
        {cos(x)}
      );
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @henri-menke. Happy to learn about this package. It does what I wanted, especially with the `shader=interp` option. However, it does no play so well with the rest of my code in tikz-3dplot. The reason being (I suppose) that the `axis` environment defines its own 3d coordinates; hence any subsequent 3d instruction is drawn w.r.t. another one. I'll have to look it up. Btw, the choice of shading function `\theta+\phi` was just an example, not the real thing.

Comment: My mistake: I only need to write the rest of the 3d code within the `axis` environment.

Answer (score 0):

After trying bits here and there, I have come up with an acceptable solution, which does use `tikz-3dplot` (with shortcomings, see below). Here's a MWE, showing a spherical triangle drawn on the shaded sphere. For different shadings, simply go to [how-to-draw-a-shaded-sphere](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54193/).

The solution below cheats partially: it does not draw a shaded sphere but rather a shaded 2D disc in perspective; therefore one has to rotate it in 3-space to make it appear like a sphere (hence the rotated coordinates). However the spherical coordinates of the arcs are true.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{80}{110}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3,tdplot_main_coords]
    % spherical background
    \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{20}{80}{0}
    \draw [ball color=white,very thin,tdplot_rotated_coords] (0,0,0) circle (1) ;
    % equator
    \draw [dashed] (0,0,0) circle (1) ;
    % spherical triangle
    \tdplotdefinepoints(0,0,0)(0.8,-0.4,-0.4)(0.4,0.8,-0.4)
    \tdplotdrawpolytopearc[thick]{1}{}{}
    \tdplotdefinepoints(0,0,0)(0.4,0.8,-0.4)(0.45,0.22,0.9)
    \tdplotdrawpolytopearc[thick]{1}{}{}
    \tdplotdefinepoints(0,0,0)(0.45,0.22,0.9)(0.8,-0.4,-0.4)
    \tdplotdrawpolytopearc[thick]{1}{}{}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Another shortcoming is the awkward syntax in `tikz-3dplot` for defining arcs, and the fact that you cannot mix it with the `coordinate` command. 
[image: spherical triangle on shaded sphere]